# C# dictionary of delegates

Tags: c#, dictionary, collections, callback

I have simple setup for my websockets where i want to make a dictionary of callbacks based on the network message.

I have my dictionary as:

```
        private Dictionary<NetworkMessage, Delegate> Callbacks;
```

So i have this code:

```
        Delegate callback;
        if (Callbacks.TryGetValue(NetworkMessage.Disconnect,out callback))
        {
            callback(); //syntax error here
        }
```

But i get:

```
Method, delegate or event expected.
```

I tried using lowercase `delegate` but that wasn't accepted for a value in the dictionary, so i am unsure how to get this working the way i was hoping to.

I don't wish to "hard code" call backs based on network messages, i want the flexibility of adding/remove them to the dictionary. So i have more flexibility when using my network code for other future projects.

How can i get this setup correctly, or is it not possible to use delegates in dictionaries?

Comment: You did not provide the signature of the Delegate. So teh compiler can not do Type-checking on it. Delegates are fully subject to type checks (using the full signature). That is one big thing they have up on the alterantive, wich is handing in callbacks at their pointers.

Comment: Yeah i realised now my whole approach isn't very good so i've refactored the whole thing now.

Comment: You may want to use `Action` instead of `Delegate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you should be using

> callback.DynamicInvoke()

instead of trying to use it directly as a method.

Maybe you should read a bit more about delegates and how they work :)